# Intellij idea gives java7 errors though compiling in java8

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-8

I have a maven project and have configured intellij to use java 8. One of my colleagues pushed a change which uses *default* keyword in an Interface. My compilation has been failing every since I synced his changes.

I am currently stumped and can't find answers online.

Below is the error message from Intellij. Currently installed `1.8.0_111-b14` version of Java on my device and `Intellij 2016.3.4`.

```
Information:18/10/17, 1:06 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 3s 442ms
Information:javac 1.8.0_111 was used to compile java sources
Error:(17, 16) java: default methods are not supported in -source 1.7 (use -source 8 or higher to enable default methods)
```

Comment: Do you hava a maven compiler plugin in your pom.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it. I had to change the  and  version in my POM file for Maven plugin.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Project Structure > Project > Project SDK. Set to 1.8.

If that doesn't help, Project Structure > Modules, and ensure your modules are set to Language Level 8

Comment: Additionally I would set Target bytecode version under Settings -> Build, Excetution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Java Compiler to 1.8

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

This will configure the JDK target version that maven is passing to the JDK for compilation

Answer (score 0):

Set your java version to `java8` and perform the update. Also, perform `invalidate cache / restart`